# Find sufficient and complete statistic: Uniform distribution, $\theta \geq 1$

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

Take a random sample $X_1,X_2, \dots X_n$  from the distribution f$(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$ for $0 \leq x \leq \theta$, where $\theta \geq 1$ (pay attention!).

I need to find an efficient estimator (in terms of MSE).

I've managed to check if $\max(1, X_{(n)})$ is sufficient and complete. But I can't transform it to get an unbiased estimator.

So, my questions are:

1. Could you suggest a suitable transformation?
2. If not, could you find another sufficient and complete estimator?

Comment: $\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}$ is the usual unbiased estimator without the $\theta>1$ constraint.  With the constraint I doubt you will do better than that for an unbiased estimator even though this is sometimes less than $1$.  When $\theta\approx 1$ but you do not know this, sometimes your estimate will be $>1$ and sometimes $<1$ and you have to allow the impossibly low estimates if you want the expectation of the estimator to be $\theta$

Comment: @Henry, thank you so much for your answer! I'm not sure I get you right. So, you're saying that there is no an effective estimator in case of $\theta \geq 1$, aren't you?

Comment: No - if I had to estimate this using frequentist methods I would choose $\max\left(1,\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}\right)$ and accept it is biased

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to find UMVUE of $\theta$
Note That:
Let $\Omega$ be a set of all unbiased estimators of 0 with finite variances and T be an unbiased estimators of $\nu$ with $E(T^2)< \infty$ and suppose that $T=h(\tilde{T})$, where $\tilde{T}$ is a sufficient statistics for $\theta \in \Theta$ and h is Borel function.Let $\Omega_{\tilde{T}}$ be the subset of $\Omega$ consisting of Borel functions of $\tilde{T}$.Then a necessary and sufficient condition for T to be a UMVUE of $\nu$ is that $E[T(X)U(X)]=0$ for any $U \in \Omega_{\tilde{T}}$ and any $\theta \in \Theta$.
So we can use this note for find the UMVUE of  $\theta$.
Let $U(X_{(n)})$ be an unbiased estimator of 0.Since $X_{(n)}$ has the Lebesgue p.d.f  $n\theta^{-n}x^{n-1}I_{(0,\theta)}(x)$

$0=\int_{0}^{1}U(x)x^{n-1}dx+\int_{1}^{\theta}U(x)x^{n-1}dx$

for all $\theta \geq 1$ .This implies that $U(x)=0$ a.e Lebesgue measure on $[1,\infty)$ and
 $\int_{0}^{1}U(x)x^{n-1}dx=0$

Consider $T=h(X_{(n)}$. To have $E(TU)=0$, we must have 
 $\int_{0}^{1}h(x)U(x)x^{n-1}dx=0$. Thus we may consider the following function

\begin{equation*}
 h(x)  = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            c& \quad  0\leq x \leq 1 \\
            x & \quad x > 1
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

Where c=1 and b are some constants.From the previous discussion, Since $E[h(X_{(n)})U(X_{(n)})]=0 \hspace{2cm} \theta \geq1$

Since $E[h(X_{(n)})]=\theta$, we obtain that

$\theta=cP(X_{(n)}\leq1)+bE[X_{(n)}I_{(1,\infty)}(X_{(n)})]=c\theta^{-n}+[\frac{bn}{n+1}](\theta-\theta^{-n})$.

Thus , $c=1$ and $b=\frac{n+1}{n}$. The UMVUE of $\theta$ is then

\begin{equation*}
 h(x)  = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1& \quad  0\leq X_{(n)} \leq 1 \\
            (1+\frac{1}{n})X_{(n)} & \quad X_{(n)} > 1
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

Comment: thank you! I've come to the same result by considering $\frac{n+1}{n}\max(1, X_{(n)}) - \frac{1}{n}I_{\{\max(1, X_{(n)}) = 1\}}$.